# Can not read spread sheet cell with different font in C#

Tags: c#, excel

A spread sheet contains 5 columns and 8 rows. First row is the header of the sheet. I have to read all the data of the cells. The last column contains blank value. C# is unable to read the 5th column of 7th and 8th row. The below code returns array index out of bound exception.

rows[7].Descendants().ElementAt(4)

I have found that the font size of 5th column of rows 7th and 8th are different from the other. If I have changed the font size then it is working fine. I don't have any explanation for this unnatural behaviour.

Please find the code base below

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
                var workBookSheet = spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name.ToString() == "Feuil1").FirstOrDefault();

                if (workBookSheet != null)
                {
                    string relationshipId = workBookSheet.Id.Value;
                    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
                    Worksheet workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                    SheetData sheetData = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
                    IEnumerable<Row> rows = sheetData.Descendants<Row>();
                    var data = rows.ElementAt(2).Descendants<Cell>().ElementAt(4);
                }
            }
```

The spreadsheet looks like below -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU7gH.jpg)

As per the sheet I have got error on row 3 column 4.

Comment: Please check how many columns and rows you have using following code: Excel.Range usedRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            int colCount = usedRange.Columns.Count;
            int rowCount = usedRange.Rows.Count;

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the value

```
string val = (Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[7, 5]).Value2.ToString();
```